# How do I display the 'description' field of an event photo from Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook-fql

I'd like to display the description that a Facebook user has entered alongside an *event's* photo.

I can get the photo from 'attachment' column in the 'stream' table but the attachment's 'description' seems to be empty despite the fact that I know something was entered on Facebook.

Here's my FQL query:

```
$fql = array(
    "permsQuery"=>"SELECT user_events, create_event FROM permissions WHERE uid = me()",
    "query1"=>'SELECT attachment FROM stream WHERE source_id = "'.$eid.'"',
);
```

And here's how I parse through to find the photo in question:

```
foreach ($ret_obj[$returnedPhotoIndex]['fql_result_set'] as $keys => $posting)
{
    foreach ($posting as $keys2 => $attachment)
    {
        foreach ($attachment['media'] as $keys3 => $media)
        {
            if (strcmp($media['photo']['fbid'], $my_photo_id) == 0) {
                $caption = $attachment['caption']; // <-- empty
                $description = $attachment['description']; // <--empty
            };
        } //media
    } //attachment
} //posting
```

Can someone tell me where I should be looking for the description associated with an event's photo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after doing a variable dump of the `$media`, I found that it's stored in the field called "alt".

How frustrating. It's called "description" on the web page but the `description` field is not the same...